# Ecommerce store customization using Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I am building an ecommerce store using Spreecommerce to sell some merchandise. In addition to the "shop" where I have all the products listed, I also need a way for users to pay for the conferences that I'll be hosting. So, if a user clicks on "Participate" on one of the conference in conferences page, they are redirected to the cart page with that conference added in their cart.

I need to understand the best way to acheive something like this.

1. Should I create "conferences" as products and give them some special taxonomy so that they are not visible in the listings page? What is the best approach to do this?
2. Should I create a separate conferences model and integrate it with cart?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach would be the easiest. Like you said, you would only need to add the proper scopes - so the special Taxonomy is not visible in the sidebar and it's products are not being shown on the global Product Listing Page (PLP) - and create a custom PLP for the Products in the Taxonomy. This way you are able to make use of all Option Types, Properties etc that Spree gives us.

The downside of this approach is that we will need to hard code an ID or name in the source code.

The 2nd approach with an additional model would either mean replicating the whole Product model and all of its relations or extending it, which would still require scoping.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to  separate the shop products and conference is as follow
1) Add one field in products table like is_conference or is_product
2) Do spree customization to update that field from product edit page
3) Then in fronted to  separate products make where(is_conference: true/false)

I this way there will be no effect on other functionalities, you need a little efforts to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at [spree digital products extension](http://spreecommerce-extensions.com/extensions/spree_digital). This may help you